# Alternate boundary conditions for this double integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

(Ignore the writing above Example 1; this question is based on Example 1 only)

I am trying to practice my ability to produce boundary conditions.

How are these  boundaries below?

$$x=1\quad to\quad x=4\\y=1\quad to\quad y=?$$

I have a feeling that I can't actually get anything for $y=?$ because you need to consider 3 regions when doing it via horizontal slices. $y=?$ probably should be a combination of $y=x$, $y=2$, and $y=-x+5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easier way is to do as follows:

$$\int_{y=1}^2dy\int_{x=y}^{5-y}f(x,y)dx$$ Otherwise, you have to consider the fig as it 's drew above and evaluate:

$$\int_{x=1}^2\int_1^{y=x}f(x,y)dA+\int_{x=2}^3\int_{y=1}^2f(x,y)dA+\int_{x=3}^4\int_{y=1}^{5-x}f(x,y)dA$$